# Is It Possible to Hide the Plugin Store in the Production Environment?

Tags: admin

I‘m a newbie and I’m learning to create simple portfolio-type sites using Craft CMS. I‘d like to remove the Plugin Store from the admin panel in the Production Environment because basically, I don't need to install plugins and the product environment plugin store is just read-only mode. I have checked the official documentation and the community without any information about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an event hook for the event `Cp::EVENT_REGISTER_CP_NAV_ITEMS` to modify the Control Panel navigation – see [Control Panel Sections](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/extend/cp-section.html) in the documentation. To determine if the site is in `devMode`, you can use the [config service](https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v3/craft-services-config.html).
Here's a little module that removes the plugin store from the navigation elements unless the site is in dev mode:

```php
<?php

namespace modules\Site;

use Craft;
use craft\events\RegisterCpNavItemsEvent;
use craft\web\twig\variables\Cp;
use yii\base\Event;

class SiteModule extends \yii\base\Module
{
    public function init()
    {
        Event::on(
            Cp::class,
            Cp::EVENT_REGISTER_CP_NAV_ITEMS,
            function(RegisterCpNavItemsEvent $event) {
                if (Craft::$app->config->general->devMode) return;
                $pluginStoreIndex = array_search(
                    'plugin-store',
                    array_column($event->navItems, 'url')
                );
                if ($pluginStoreIndex === false) return;
                unset($event->navItems[$pluginStoreIndex]);
            }
        );

        parent::init();
    }
}
```

To make this work, you need to put that code into a site module and add it to the `bootstrap` section in the `app.php` config. See [How to Build a Module](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/extend/module-guide.html) for details.

Comment: I have solved this problem with your guidance, thank you so much!

Comment: @Colt Glad I could help! Would you mind marking my answer as accepted? Thanks!

Comment: Thank you again!

Answer (score 2):

I must say that I don't understand the rationale behind hiding the Settings in production but not the Plugin Store.

The only action you can really do in production is upgrade to a Pro licence if you don't have one already, so this might be the reason but I think the link at the bottom of the page there if you need it.

For me the 'allowAdminChanges' => false should also hide the Plugin Store or another trigger like 'showPluginStore' should be added.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the [CP Nav plugin](https://plugins.craftcms.com/cp-nav)

Comment: Thank you very much!